# Accessing Dynamically created control (textbox) in a dynamically created eventhandler

Tags: c#, .net, eventhandler

I am trying to access my dynamically created TextBox in C#, inside an event handler of a Button.

```
     void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        this.Width=600;
        this.Height=400;

        this.FormBorderStyle= FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        TextBox t=new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(t);
        t.Location = new Point(60,40);
        Label Mylable=new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(Mylable);
        Mylable.Location=new Point(15,43);
        Mylable.Text="string : ";
        t.Width=200;
        t.Name="MyText";
        t.Refresh();
        Button Myb=new Button();
        Myb.Location=new Point(270,40);
        this.Controls.Add(Myb);
        Myb.Text="Reverse it!";
        Myb.Name="Mybo";
        Myb.Click += new EventHandler(this.Myb_Clicked);
        this.Refresh();                     
    }

    void Myb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

              // HOW SHOULD I GAIN ACCESS to MyText.Text HERE
              MessageBox.Show();

    }
```

Comment: On SO You thank people by accepting their answer lol

Answer (score 2):

Give a `name` to your dynamic `TextBox`:

```
 TextBox t=new TextBox();
 t.Name = "MyTextBox";
 this.Controls.Add(t);
```

And then:

```
void Myb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string text = this.Controls["MyTextBox"].Text;

}
```

Comment: @danish yes, what's wrong with this way? you can extend this way if there is more than one textbox.But if we use your way then we need to know textbox count in compile-time which is not the case I think.

Comment: String comparison. I personally do not like it and it is proven to be slower.

Comment: Do notice that you get a Control, not a TextBox. If you need TextBox specific properties you need to cast first. This code works because Text happens to be a property on the Control class.

Comment: @rene Text property is defined in Control class,therefore it's a common property for all Form controls. but generally, you'r right.

Comment: Now that you have edited your comment, there are lot of questions to be answered. You are trying to make this thing as generic as possible. Please, even with that thought process, I would say you are wrong. Not that I am after that ever valuable nanosecond saved by avoiding string comparison, but I find your way just plain wrong.

Comment: I think it was George Carlin: "I don't have pet peeve. I have major psychotic hatred."

Comment: @danish I don't care your opinion. _Not at all._

Comment: Hehe, it is not opinion. This way is just plain wrong. There are better ways.

Comment: This  is opinion because you didn't explain what is wrong.this is not a string comparison, the `Name` property identifies a Control.And the Control collection is contains all the Controls in the Form.I'm accessing a control with it's name.So there is nothing wrong here.This approach can be extended for more than one textbox as I said earlier.But your approach cannot be applied in that case because there will be only one textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong answer: `object sender` is the `TextBox`. You can cast sender to textbox and use it.

A decent way would be to make your textbox a class level member. And then you have access to it. If not, link `TextBox.Text` to a string property and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a reference to your TextBox in your class

```
 publc class MyForm: Form
 {

     TextBox myBox = null;  // class member

     void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         this.Width=600;
         this.Height=400;

         this.FormBorderStyle= FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
         TextBox t=new TextBox();
         myBox = t; // keep it for future reference

         // rest of your code
   }

   void Myb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

          if (myBox !=null)
          {
                myBox.Text= "Clicked!";
          }
          MessageBox.Show();
    }
}
```